# Finding words in a file present in a different file

Tags: text, notepad++

I have a file with a list of properties.

```
Name
Description
BogusProperty_the_first
```

The full file has some 200 properties

I also have an xml file that references properties in the previous list, containing entries like;

```
 <Item value="#Name#" length="32" description="Name" />
```

I want to remove from the first file all entries that are/are not present in the second file.

I do not need a perfect fit, it's OK if I treat some entries as being present in the second file when in fact they are not, so it's sufficient to test that "Description" occurs somewhere in the second file, I don't need to test that value="#Description#" occurs in a tag at the appropriate place in the DOM. 
It would be bad to treat entries in the first file as not being in the second file if in fact they where.

The solution does not need to be completely automated or a single button click, but I do not want to check each item in the first file separately.

I am using notepad++, but would be open to using other tools if applicable.

The problem is small enough that writing a separate program to handle it, while straight forward, would not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I realised that notepad++ can solve this by copy pasting the second file into a copy of the first file.

The procedure I used was the following;

- Write a seperate line in the first file with text that does not occur in the either of the two files. In my case I used `asdf1234`.
- Copy the contents of the second file into the first.
- Search for the following regexp with ".matches newlines" checked.

  ```
  (?:\n|\r)([^\n\r]+)(?=(?:\n|\r).*asdf1234.*\1)
  ```
- Replace with nothing.
- ???
- Profit

To keep the entries that do occur in the second file use `(?:\n|\r)([^\n\r]+)(?=(?:\n|\r))(?!.*asdf1234.*\1)` to search.